# Image hover CSS for revolution slider

Tags: css, wordpress, image, hover, revolution-slider

I'm using revolution slider and I'm stuck with a problem. As an example I use the original demo from here: https://revolution.themepunch.com/wordpress-photography-slider.

On the tab 'portfolio' you see images that shrink in size with a transition and look a bit darker when you hover over them. This is what I want as well but I can't figure out how.

In revolution slider you can add classes, ID's and CSS to specific images so what I probably need is a CSS code that makes this possible. I've tried several codes I found online but none of them do the trick because they all come with an html part as well.

My guess was: the image is already there, I don't need the html part, only assign classes or id's to the images and then give each image the same kind of CSS code.

Am I on the right track with this? And can anyone help me with the code for it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a class, then do some css

for example:

```
<img class="slider-img">

.slider-img:hover {

{
```

let me know if you need help with the css.

EDIT:

try this.

wrap each of your images around 2 divs, slider-img and img-wrap:

```
<div class="slider-img">
    <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/stock-image/stock-image-15.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

then do some css:

```
.slider-img {
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-img:hover .img-wrap {
  background-color: black;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  -o-transform: scale(0.7);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.slider-img:hover .img-wrap img{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

basically what the css is doing is that when you hover over the main div (.slider-img), the div containing the image (.img-wrap) gets scaled down by 70% by the css -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);

it also gets a background color of black with an opacity of 80%. this gives the darkened image effect.

-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out; gives a smooth transition effect.

if you are wondering why there are 5 different lines of css for the same thing, thats because each line targets specific browsers. -o- is opera, -moz- is firefox etc.

also, make sure to change the .slider-img width to match your needs.

check out the working example on js fiddle:

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/dq6L72mo/)

Comment: I'm going to try this, I'll let you know if I got it working myself. Thanks for now!!

Comment: I tried some CSS I found online and it definitely did something. I saw the image with class "slider-img" resize in width when I hovered over. So it's good to know that it works!

But I do need help with the CSS. Looking at the demo I sent, I thought it wouldn't be hard, but I'm reading things about browser prefixes and I'm not that far with my knowledge in coding.

Following the example I know I would need something to shrink the image on hover with a transition in the code because it shrinks in a nice motion but I wouldn't know how to create this myself.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: send me your html for your slider and ill help you out

Comment: check out me edited answer, let me know if you have questions

Comment: This worked like a charm!
Still editing the final results to my needs but you were a very big help!!

Comment: And thanks for replying so soon as well, by reading through a lot of the revolution slider related questions I wasn't sure if I would even get an answer.
Thanks a lot, appreciate it very much!